# Custom Validator on: :create not running on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord, customvalidator

I have a rails application for creating volumes and have written two custom validators using ActiveModel::Validator.

*volume.rb:*

```
    class Volume < ActiveRecord::Base
      include UrlSafeCode
      include PgSearch::Model
      include ActiveModel::Validations
      validates :user_id, presence: true
      validates_with Validators::VolumeValidator
      validates_with Validators::CreateVolumeValidator, on: :create

    def self.digest text
      Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(text)
    end

    def text=(new_text)
      new_text.rstrip!
      new_text.downcase!
      self.text_digest = Volume.digest(new_text)
      super(new_text)
    end
```

**My Problem:** The CreateVolumeValidator checks if a record with the same text_digest is already in the database. I only want to run this when creating a new volume so that I can still update existing volumes. However, adding on: :create to the CustomVolumeValidator causes the validator to stop working.

I've read through a lot of the other entries about similar issues and haven't found a solution. I am pretty sure I am missing something about when different attributes are getting created, validated, and saved, but I haven't worked with custom validations much, and I'm lost.

Here is the other relevant code.

*volumes_controller.rb*

```
  def new
    @volume = Volume.new
  end

  def create
    our_params = params
      .permit(:text, :description)

    if params[:text].nil?
      render :retry
      return
    end

    text = params[:text].read.to_s
    text_digest = Volume.digest(text)   

    @description = our_params[:description]

    begin
      @volume = Volume.where(text_digest: text_digest)
        .first_or_create(text: text, user: current_user, description: our_params[:description])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      retry
    end

    if @volume.invalid?
      render :retry
      return
    end

    render :create

  end

  def edit
    get_volume
  end

  def update

    get_volume
    unless @volume
      render nothing: true, status: :not_found
      return
    end

    @volume.update(params.require(:volume).permit(:text, :description))

    if @volume.save
      redirect_to volume_path(@volume.code)
    else
      flash[:notice] = @volume.errors.full_messages.join('\n')
      render :edit
    end

  end

  def get_volume
    @volume = Volume.where(code: params.require(:code)).first
  end
```

*create_volume_validator.rb*

```
class Validators::CreateVolumeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(volume)
        existing_volume = Volume.where(text_digest: volume.text_digest).first
        if existing_volume 
          existing_volume_link = "<a href='#{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.volume_path(existing_volume.code)}'>here</a>."
          volume.errors.add :base, ("This volume is already part of the referral archive and is available " + existing_volume_link).html_safe
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is for all `Volume` records to have unique `text_digest`, you are better off with a simple `:uniqueness` validator (and associated DB unique index).

However, the reason your existing code isn't working is:

```rb
Volume.where(text_digest: text_digest).first_or_create(...)
```

This returns either the first `Volume` with the matching `text_digest` or creates a new one. But that means if there is a conflict, no object is created, and therefore your (`on: :create`) validation doesn't run. Instead, it simply sets `@volume` to the existing object, which is, by definition, valid. If there is no matching record, it *does* call your validator, but there's nothing to validate because you've already proved there is no `text_digest` conflict.

You could resolve by replacing the `first_or_create` with `create`, but again, you are vastly better off with a unique index & validator (with custom message if you like).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Changing first_or_create to create worked, and I am working on creating a uniqueness validation like you described.